# Dynamically adding controls onto MapBasic dialog?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I have seen a lot examples with dialog creation, like:

```
    Dialog
    Title "Title"
    Width 198 Height 52
   Control Button
        Title "Обзор"
        Width 50 Height 15
        Position 133, 6
        ID 5001
        Calling SetTextEditFolder
    Control Button
        Title "Создать"
        Position 15, 28
        Width 50 Height 15
        Calling CallforYes
```

But is just a static dialog.  It's possible to dinnamically add anf remove controls from dialog?  For example i want press button or select value in list edit and change set of controls in dialog.
Any advises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really possible to dynamically create a dialog in MapBasic unfortunately. I had thought it may be possible to use the `Run Command` statement to run a dynamically created dialog command but testing confirmed this wasn't possible. The `Run Command` statement is apparently limited to commands you can run from the MapBasic window from within MapInfo.

This means that the only way to do this is to create as many controls as you may need and keep them hidden unless required at runtime. You will probably also want to determine the size of the dialog box based on the number of controls you are going to show - this can also be resolved at runtime.

Once you know how many controls you are going to need then you can go and unhide them, size your dialog, and position any other controls (e.g. ok button) appropriately.

See [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mapinfo-l/jyJtt_-GgFQ) for a bit more info.

Comment: Your aswer make me sad. But i cant find another solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can create Dialogs in .NET with Visual Studio (VB.NET or C#) and use such controls in your MapBasic.

Check your MapBasic folder `Samples\DOTNET\NAMEDVIEWS` to see an example.

This is a simple example I use in my application:

C# Code:

```
internal partial class FormDatePicker: Form
{

   /// <summary>
   /// Create new form, with specified initial date
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="intialDate">The initially selected day</param>
   public FormDatePicker(DateTime intialDate, string caption)
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.Text = caption;
      this.SelectedDate = intialDate;
      datePicker.MaxSelectionCount = 1;
      datePicker.TodayDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
      datePicker.DateChanged += new DateRangeEventHandler(this.datePicker_DateChanged);
      datePicker.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.datePicker_MouseDown);
      this.Shown += new EventHandler(this.SizeForm);
      this.Size = new Size(178, 162);

   }


   /// <summary>
   /// Property holding selected day
   /// </summary>
   public DateTime SelectedDate { get; private set; }

   /// <summary>
   /// EventHandler when user selects a day
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="sender"></param>
   /// <param name="e"></param>
   private void datePicker_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
   {
      datePicker.MouseDown -= new MouseEventHandler(this.datePicker_MouseDown);
      this.SelectedDate = datePicker.SelectionStart;
      this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
      this.Close();
   }

   private void datePicker_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
      datePicker.DateChanged -= new DateRangeEventHandler(this.datePicker_DateChanged);
      this.SelectedDate = datePicker.SelectionStart;
      this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
      this.Close();
   }


   /// <summary>
   /// Set form to proper size when shown the first time
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="sender"></param>
   /// <param name="e"></param>
   private void SizeForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      ClientSize = datePicker.Size;
   }

}

public static class DatePicker
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Shows a .NET MonthCalendar Dialog where user can select a date.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="initial">The initial date when MonthCalendar shows up</param>
  /// <returns>The selected day in format "yyyyMMdd"</returns>
  public static int PickDate(int initial, string caption)
  {
     FormDatePicker form = new FormDatePicker(DateTime.ParseExact(initial.ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), caption);
     if ( form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK )
        return Convert.ToInt32(form.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
     else
        return initial;
  }
}
```

And the call in MapBasic:

```
Declare Method PickDate Class "MyApp.DatePicker" Lib "MyApp.dll" (ByVal initial As Integer, ByVal caption As String) As Integer


Function SelectDate(ByVal initial As Date, ByVal caption As String) As Date
    SelectDate = NumberToDate(PickDate(initial, caption))
End Function
```